# R - plotMapDomFlows ("flows" package) on Leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, geography, gis, cartography

There is a package in R called "flows" [(details here)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flows/vignettes/flows.html) which allows you to plot a map of flow interraction (through the function **plotMapDomFlows()** from a squared matrix of flows. Here is an example, with data contained in the package, of what the output looks like :

```
# Import data
data(nav)
myflows <- prepflows(mat = nav, i = "i", j = "j", fij = "fij")

# Remove the matrix diagonal
diag(myflows) <- 0

# Select flows that represent at least 20% of the sum of outgoing flows for 
# each urban area.
flowSel1 <- firstflows(mat = myflows/rowSums(myflows)*100, method = "xfirst", 
                       k = 20)


# Select the dominant flows (incoming flows criterion)
flowSel2 <- domflows(mat = myflows, w = colSums(myflows), k = 1)

# Combine selections
flowSel <- myflows * flowSel1 * flowSel2

# Node weights
inflows <- data.frame(id = colnames(myflows), w = colSums(myflows))

# Plot dominant flows map
opar <- par(mar = c(0,0,2,0))
sp::plot(GE, col = "#cceae7", border = NA)
plotMapDomFlows(mat = flowSel, spdf = UA, spdfid = "ID", w = inflows, wid = "id",
                wvar = "w", wcex = 0.05, add = TRUE)
```

[image: Output of the code above]

**I would like to have these lines and polygons on a leaflet map using R.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. We plan to update the package soon. This feature (lines and points export) may be among the new features introduced by the update.